# Use dd to backup device over the network

Tags: linux, networking, backup, dd

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to the network along with a USB stick. Is it possible to use the dd command on my Raspberry Pi and automatically upload the iso to my Mac?

What I mean is on my pi could I do something like this: `sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=192.168.1.248/path/to/iso` (ip address is my Mac)? If this is possible how would I do this?

I will be happy to make a server on my Mac if I need to.

Comment: I don't have time to do a proper answer, but basically what you need is NFS. Mount some shared directory, and `dd` to it.

Answer (score 2):

Mount to a remote directory on the Mac, using whatever interface you prefer (samba, nfs, etc).  Then just dd to a file on the mount point.

Answer (score 1):

No, dd will not work like that, but you can use ssh and redirection to do what you're looking for:

ssh user@pi "dd if=/dev/mmcblk0" > pi.iso

Answer (score 0):

The [canonical answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132800/2974) from [unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) is to pipe through `ssh`.

> ```
> $ dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -1 - | ssh user@remote dd of=image.gz
> ```

Comment: So user@remote would be my Mac?

Comment: @iProgram: Yes.